# if a VNC server connection failed, would an active process keep running?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, vnc-server

This may be a silly question,

1. If I am running infinite loop processes in a shell from a VNC created desktop ubuntu GUI. After some time if the VNC server was not able to connect (because of a brute force attack or something, with error - `connection refused`), Will the processes still be running? or does it gets killed?
2. If i use nomachine, and nomachine gets hung, will the process running, get killed, or will it be still running on the server?

Note : I use cronjobs to trigger python scripts which will run all day, so stability is important, hence above questions

Comment: If I understand you, you're connecting via VNC and then, in the terminal on the remote server, running a little infinite loop script.  The answer to your question depends on how it is denying service.  If it is using up all your memory, it could cause the VNC server to crash (so the process would be dead).  But if the script is just using up CPU, the vnc might just be idle but unable to respond to your request.

Comment: VNC is not opening because of brute force attack, script is not consuming much CPU or memory.  In this scenario, if i am not able to connect to vncserver , the underlying process or cronjobs will be working fine correct?

Comment: The VNC server itself is getting attacked?  I don't know then.  It could be either way depending on the VNC server's architecture and what, if any, bugs are getting tripped.

Comment: im using tigervncserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if server is up the things you do on VNC should be up and running

Comment: Are they documentation/references on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Connections can be refused for many reasons. Attempting to connect to the wrong port, or the VNC service might be down, or the machine might be so CPU bound that it times out before responding.

Have you tried to ssh to the machine, using a command line instead of VNC? That will tell you a lot. If ssh also fails the problem is not with VNC. From ssh, run `top` and look at the load at the top right of the screen. Load factors over 1.0 could be problematic.
http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html

It is more likely that other problems are causing the issue, instead of an attack.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding! But the question wasn't "Why VNC service is down", It's actually - "If it's not connecting what happens to the underlying active processes ?" For the sake of argument, let's say the CPU is free.  A typical scenario for this case is When VNC is running because of bruteforce attck VNC gets locked.